# how to get file descriptor from ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, file-descriptor

I'm using ffmpeg in my c++ project, and I need to get the file descriptor for the opened file, something like this:

```
    AVFormatContext* pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "C:\\a.avi", NULL, NULL);
    uint64_t fileDescriptor = getDescriptor();
```

Is it possible to get the descriptor and how?

Answer (score 4):

In *some* cases, the following might work:

```
#include "libavformat/avio.h"

[..]

AVIOContext *pb = pFormatCtx->pb;
URLContext *url = pb->opaque;
int fd = ffurl_get_file_handle(url);
```

It should be obvious that you're accessing internal variables here, so if it works, consider yourself lucky. Don't ship code that uses this, since it's not public API.

Comment: `pb->opaque` is not a pointer to `URLContext` now. It's a pointer to `AVIOInternal`.